# Generate new Font every time or use pre-generated collection of Fonts?

Tags: java

I have a method which decides what font size to use for drawing a string. I'm using java.awt.Font.

Font size depends on string length and height, and I use do-while loop to decrease font size until the string fits targetHeight. So in general it looks something like this:

```
private void decideOnFontSize(String text) {
    int fontSize = 72;
    do {
        font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
        // Calculating things...
        fontSize -= 2;
    } while (textHeight >= targetHeight);
}
```

With this approach I need to instantiate a new Font object every time when I need a smaller font size. Method *decideOnFontSize* is a part of a service in a public API, so it could be called pretty often. At first sight, instantiating new Font looks pretty wasteful in this case.

Another approach is to create a pre-defined collection of Fonts and get them as required. So I could create a utility class like this:

```
public class FontsUtil {

    private static Map<Integer, Font> fonts = new HashMap<>();

    public static final Integer MAX_FONT_SIZE = 72;
    public static final Integer MIN_FONT_SIZE = 10;

    static {

        String fontName = "Arial";

        for(int fontSize = MAX_FONT_SIZE; fontSize >= MIN_FONT_SIZE; fontSize -= 2) {
            fonts.put(fontSize, new Font(fontName, Font.PLAIN, fontSize));
        }
    }

    public static Font getFontBySize(Integer fontSize) {
        return fonts.get(fontSize);
    }
}
```

...and then I could get these pre-defined Fonts in do-while loop, so my method will look like this:

```
private void decideOnFontSize(String text) {
    int fontSize = FontsUtil.MAX_FONT_SIZE;
    do {
        font = FontsUtil.getFontBySize(fontSize);
        // Calculating things...
        fontSize -= 2;
    } while (textHeight >= targetHeight);
}
```

To my mind, the second approach looks better, because (in theory) it consumes less resources. Am I right, or it doesn't really matter?

**UPD:** More specifically, I create one or more TextLayout objects using LineBreakMeasurer, because I have two initial params to fit: targetWidth and targetHeight. So my do-while looks like this:

```
List<TextLayout> lines;
int fontSize = font.getSize();
int textHeight;
do {
    font = FontsUtil.getFontBySize(fontSize);
    g2d.setFont(font);

    lines = splitStringIntoPiecesToFitTargetWidth(text, targetWidth, g2d);
    textHeight = getTextHeight(lines);

    fontSize -= 2;
} while (textHeight >= targetHeight);
```

*where *font* is an instance variable

And method *splitStringIntoPiecesToFitTargetWidth* looks like this:

```
private List<TextLayout> splitStringIntoPiecesToFitTargetWidth(String string,
int width, Graphics2D g2d) {
    List<TextLayout> lines = new ArrayList<>();

    AttributedString attributedString = new AttributedString(string);
    attributedString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, font);
    LineBreakMeasurer lineBreakMeasurer =
        new LineBreakMeasurer(attributedString.getIterator(), g2d.getFontRenderContext());

    while (lineBreakMeasurer.getPosition() < string.length()) {
        lines.add(lineBreakMeasurer.nextLayout(width));
    }

    return lines;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Would you mind sharing some more details, more specifically, what are you using that requires fonts, i.e. where is this class coming from (I'm assuming awt)? This would help us determine whether the instantiation is costly or not. P.S. Really good first question, by the way!

Comment: Hi! I updated my question, I hope it helps :) Yes, it's all about awt. I'm creating one or several TextLayout objects to fit some pre-defined bounds (target width and height). In this case, I need to split string into several lines using LineBreakMeasurer, and if these lines doesn't fit targetHeight, I reduce font size and repeat the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of the Font.java source I could find is [this one](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/awt/Font.java) from OpenJDK 8. It defines the following constructor:

```
public Font(String name, int style, int size) {
    this.name = (name != null) ? name : "Default";
    this.style = (style & ~0x03) == 0 ? style : 0;
    this.size = size;
    this.pointSize = size;
}
```

To be honest, this doesn't feel like it'll be the bane of your existence performance-wise. I would suggest leaving the version that instantiates new fonts, as it reads easier. If performance does show to be a real issue/concern, you can always go with the other option.

P.S. You should benchmark it, just in case. If the difference is noticeable (I'd put the line at anything >50% faster, but it's up to you), maybe the second option is worth it.

Comment: Your take about constructor really makes sense, didn't think about it. Anyway, I think it's worth benchmarking to make it clear, thanks for the idea.